# effect size for meta-analysis when study data violate normality assumptions?

Tags: regression, correlation, regression-coefficients, meta-analysis, effect-size

I'm looking for advice regarding what effect size to use for meta-analysis.  Our question is whether the number of individuals in a group increases per-capita productivity of that group.  Studies are from a wide range of species, which range in group sizes from 10s to 1000s.

Our initial idea was to take total productivity in each group, divide by the group size to get per capita productivity for the group, and then calculate the pearson correlation (r) between this per capita productivity and group size.  We would then meta-analyze this effect, with positive r indicating increasing efficiency with group size, negative r indicating reduced efficiency with increasing group size.

In gathering data from the literature, i find that many datasets violate the homoscedasticity assumption, with much greater variance in Y for small values of X.  Here's are a couple examples:
[image: a particularly egregious example]

[image: a second example with different X scale]
We had planned to use correlation coefficients (r) for our effect size, but i assume that studies with data like this violate some important assumptions about normality.  Is this violation damning for a study like this?

Since we have access to raw data for many studies, one option i have come up with is to log-transform the number of individuals and the TOTAL productivity (not per capita productivity), and then meta-analyze the slope of the regression to determine if per capita productivity declines with size (slopes <1) or not.  log log transforming seems to solve the unbalanced variance issue, at least for a few such data sets.
[image]

[image: log-log plot example 2]
Does this seem like a better approach than using the correlation coefficiecnt of the per capita data when data are structured like this?  Other suggestions?

Comment: That tells you that doubling the number of individuals doubles the total output but your original question was about per capita output.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I agree that it'll tell you if doubling the number of individuals doubles the total output.  However, if the slope is significantly less than 1, then doubling the number of individuals does not double the output, meaning that each individual couldn't have been as productive (or the slope would be one).  I believe this is the same as saying a larger group produces proportionately less, per individual, than a smaller group, right?

Comment: That's true but in that case would you not want to meta-analyse the slopes not $r$?

Comment: Yes, i think my original phrasing is not clear...i'm editing it to hopefully clarify.  I'm proposing meta-analyzing the slope from the log-log regression, rather than the correlation coefficient of size vs per capita productivity (r).